# DevelopmentServerPort merge conflict

Tags: visual-studio-2008, merge, svn, ankhsvn

I have a team of people working on a Visual Studio (C#) project, and we keep running into this problem where there is a merge conflict in the project file on the DevelopmentServerPort.  Apparently the DevelopmentServerPort is saved in the project file, rather than in user settings.

Is there any way to solve this, other than forcing it to a specific port?  That won't work because we have multiple devs developing on terminal servers, and they can't all use the same port.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the project properties for the web project, uncheck "Apply server setting to all users (store in project file)". This makes it a per-user setting.

Comment: Do unchecking this has any other side effect? Are there some "server settings" (other than DevelopmentServerPort), that I could want to keep "per-project"?